# Lubuntu 18.04 LXTerminal - strange behavior?

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, lxterminal

On a Dell Latitude 3540 laptop, sometimes an open LXTerminal window will "go funky" after suspend/resume, and result in the following behavior:

[image: Corrupted LXTerminal]

What seems to happen is,

- Linefeeds are ignored.
- Tabs are all different sizes.
- Typed text does not echo to the terminal at all.

(Here at the first prompt I typed 'ls', then 'cd Downloads', 'ls' again, then 'cd ~' and 'ls'.)

Any idea what is going on, and is there a way to fix this without closing the terminal and re-opening it?

I have [Oibaf's drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) installed, but doubt this is purely a video issue.

Comment: Looks like your `tty` settings got messed up. `stty sane` should help, also `man stty`

Comment: Thanks Waltinator, that looks like it fixes it. If you could make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your tty settings got messed up. `stty sane` should help, also `man stty`.